Angular 18 -- Error: The injectable 'Http2' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available
I am upgrading an old project of mine from Angular ~7 to ~18.  After fixing ALL the TS warnings and errors, the project compiles successfully. However, when I run npm start and hit localhost:4200 I am facing an error that is proving difficult to nail down.
Error: The injectable 'Http2' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available. JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider using AOT mode instead. Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server', or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping. — chunk-3NVXP5OT.js:3825
My project is bootstrapped in main.ts like this:
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

I have already verified that @angular/compiler is defined in package.json as a dependency:
"@angular/compiler": "18.0.1",
and the @angular/compiler-cli is a devDependency:
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.1",
within my app.module.ts I am using:
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptorsFromDi } from '@angular/common/http';
and then setting this on the module's providers property like this:
providers: [provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()), ...]
I have a service, UserService that injects the angular http object and that is the only place actually using it.
My guess is that I've missed a step in the upgrade process.  Jumping nearly 10 major versions leaves a lot of room for errors but I feel so close!  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Just trying to find documentation about the http client is proving challenging.  Take a look at the official docs which are sparse to say the least https://angular.dev/guide/http

It would be wisest to migrate through major versions sequentially, making a large jump through this many versions, might leave other errors, if you get to fix this one.

Figured it out.  For anyone who arrives here in the future, here's what fixed it for me:
Turns out I was still importing the old Http stuff from angular:
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
This was happening in a few files, and I was using the Http in my service constructor, which was using dependency-injection.
constructor(private http: Http) {}
So, despite there being no typescript errors this was still an error, I guess?  You cannot, or should not, have the older Http interface being used in your application after you've fully migrated to the new version using
providers: [provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()), ...],
in your main app.module.ts

I had the same problem but with stomp service 2. It occured while migrating angular version to 18 and using the build configuration "browser-esbuild".
Error: The injectable 'StompService2' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

To fix this I used this in the service that used stomp service 2
import '@angular/compiler';

